# Python не запускает файл

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Всем привет! Использую Python 2.7.17. Не могу запустить ни одну программу. Пробовала запускать в Python command line, в IDLE, а также из командной строки. Результат примерно одинаковый:

В среде командного Python

```
>>> test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Непосредственно из командной строки:

```
> C:\Python27>python.exe test.py
python.exe: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Код программы тривиальный, написан специально для проверки работоспособности:

```
a=2
print a
```

Что делать? Почему файлы .py и .pyw не распознаются?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант вообще неверный.

Во втором варианте нужно указывать полный путь к файлу. python.exe ищет test.py в той же папке, откуда идёт вызов программы (в данном случае в C:\Python27), а вряд ли test.py там находится (т.е. совершенно точно он находится не там).  Или же запускать из папки, где лежит test.py.

Comment: Или `cd путь_к_файлу`, потом запускать

Comment: поняла в чём проблема - действительно из заданной директории файлы .py запускаются. спасибо1

Answer (score 0):

зажимаешь shift + пкм по папке где лежит test.py, открыть окно команд, python test.py